# Is it possible to send json data along with a django template in an HttpResponse

Tags: ajax, json, django, http

I would like to avoid making an ajax call to get the data I need once my page is loaded on the client. So I want to send this data along with the template.

I could put it in json format in a data-* attributs of a tag in my html page, but is there a clean way to do this?

What I would like is something which does both things:

```
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'obj':'val'}), mimetype="application/json")
```

and

```
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: Why can't you just put your JSON in the context like any other variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Try:

```
import json
template_context = {
        'my_json':   json.dumps(json_object) 
    }

return render_template('index.html', **template_context )
```

In the template:

```
<script>
    myJSON = {{ my_json|safe }};
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, so instead of putting the json in a tag attribute, it is better to put it as a script. Thanks!